# <Include> an xml file with a fab button as it is

Tags: android, xml, include, floating-action-button

I want to include to an xml file an other xml file that contains a fab button exactly as it is.The problem is that when i `<include layout="@layout/fab`
it shows my fab button at the top left corner on the screen instead of bottom right.

Here is my xml file(**ConstraintLayout**)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".PlanPage.PlanPageView">


<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/activity_fab_button"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is the fab button xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
android:src="@drawable/ic_plusphoto_fab"
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
/>
```

Comment: can you try to add `marginBottom` in `include`??

Comment: I've added `android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"` just to check and it doesn't work

Comment: please try to set `alignParant` `bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This attribute inside the fab xml:

```
android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
```

has no effect when you include the layout inside another layout.  
You must set attributes to this layout:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/activity_fab_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

if it's valid. 
If the host layout of the include layout is not `LinearLayout`, then you must set other attributes, like 
`alignParentBottom` for `RelativeLayout`, or
constraint it to the Bottom and End for a ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Of course you must set `layout_height` and `layout_width` to `wrap_content` and then set the appropriate attribute depending on the host layout.

Comment: Doesn't work :/ It seems so legit and still doesn't work :P

Comment: Post the host layout

Comment: Ok just did it!

Comment: You did not constraint it. It's a ConstraintLayout not a LinearLayout.

Comment: It works that way but will it be ok in all the screen sizes?(just asking)

Comment: The attributes for `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` and    `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` work for all screen sizes. After all the ConstraintLayout was presented as the most efficient layout.